# Google Play Services location and geofencing APIs not working properly on Genymotion

Tags: android, google-play-services, genymotion

I've got two problems using the latest version (1.3.1) of the Genymotion emulator, related to the Google Play Services location APIs. More specifically:

1) The LocationClient only works (i.e. sends location events when I use the Genymotion GPS menu) when I request location updates with the [PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY) flag. The two other LocationRequest modes, PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY and PRIORITY_LOW_POWER don't work.

2) Geofencing, on the other hand, doesn't work at all. When I add geofences via `LocationClient.addGeofences()`, the `LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener` callback returns the [GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener.html) status code.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issues? And does anyone have a workaround? For now, I am only testing my app's location services using the PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY flag and geofencing on a real device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the issue regarding geolocation a few days ago and contacted Genymotion about it. They said they do not currently support Geolocation features but may consider implementing them in the future.

I don't know the answer to your first question as I haven't had this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried contacting them with their web form, but that doesn't work either! (gives me a user-not-authenticated error, although I'm logged in)

Comment: Hmm, I contacted them through there. Anyway, they communicate with this email, so you can probably email them directly: support@genymobile.com

Comment: I contacted them and confirmed the problem. There is no workaround currently. I will update this thread when a version is released that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem here. Using the latest (6.5.x) Google Play services Location API I get no location updates with Genymotion when using `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`.

This is when running on an S3 Android 4.3 image.